# How to combine worksheets from more than 2 files into one worksheet in 1 file?

Tags: excel

I have, say, 3 excel files, each contains 1 worksheet, those 3 worksheets have identical column header names.

File A has a worksheet named "AA" with column header names "IC", "Name".
File B has a worksheet named "BB" with column header names "IC", "Name".
File C has a worksheet named "CC" with column header names "IC", "Name".
.
.
.

Now I'd like to combine those the values under "IC", "Name" in worksheet "AA", "BB", and "CC" from File A, B, C into one worksheet in a file.

File ZZ has worksheet named "zz" with column header names "IC", "Name" that have all rows values from File A, B, and C...

Could anyone share how to do it ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply use copy and paste? Copy contents of file A into an empty workbook, file Z. Then copy all of the data rows in file B (excluding the headers) and paste below the existing data in file Z. Repeat for file C.

Comment: sorry no... it will be too tedious, I have more than 100 excel files generated by an application system :(

Comment: Oh I see. I thought you only had 3 but that was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what conventions your workbooks (you call them files) use, I've created a macro that does as you ask but makes some assumptions. This does exactly as you ask, but it might need some alterations based on your files.

**Assumptions:**

- All workbook header rows `IC` and `Name` are located in cells `A1` and `B1`, respectively
- All workbooks will be open before running this macro
- The macro will be initiated from the `Parent Workbook`, which is assumed to be the WorkBook that will house the final result
- All values for each workbook are in the first sheet of that workbook

**Code**

```
Public Sub CombineAllOpenWorkbooks()
    Dim parentWb As Workbook, childWb As Workbook
    Dim destinationWs As Worksheet, sourceWs As Worksheet

    Dim highestRowCount As Integer
    Dim firstColumnRowCount As Integer
    Dim secondColumnRowCount As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'this holds reference to the parent workbook, which is where all the values go
    Set parentWb = Application.Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name)
    Set destinationWs = parentWb.Sheets(1)

    'for each workbook open that isn't the aprent workbook, find the last cell,
    'select it, copy its values, then paste them at the end of the parent workbooks
    'current values
    For Each childWb In Application.Workbooks
        If childWb.Name <> parentWb.Name Then
            Set sourceWs = childWb.Sheets(1)
            firstColumnRowCount = sourceWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            secondColumnRowCount = sourceWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

            highestRowCount = firstColumnRowCount
            If firstColumnRowCount < secondColumnRowCount Then
                highestRowCount = secondColumnRowCount
            End If

            'copy from below the 'IC/Name' headers to the last cell that contains values
            sourceWs.Range(sourceWs.Cells(2, 1), sourceWs.Cells(highestRowCount, 2)).Copy

            firstColumnRowCount = destinationWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            secondColumnRowCount = destinationWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

            highestRowCount = firstColumnRowCount
            If firstColumnRowCount < secondColumnRowCount Then
                highestRowCount = secondColumnRowCount
            End If

            'paste the previously copied values to the end of the parent workbokos values
            destinationWs.Range("A" & highestRowCount + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next childWb
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[To add this VBA to your workbook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx), you must Open the `Developer Tab` of the **PARENT Workbook**, choose `Visual Basic` from the menu, open `Sheet 1` from the left menu, then paste the code there.

Here are some images of the workbooks I used during testing (ParentWorkbook, FileA, FileB):

**All three workbooks BEFORE running macro:**
[image]

**Parent workbook AFTER running macro:**
[image]

Please note that this code was created quickly and limited testing has been done. It can certainly be cleaned up and redundancy within the code can be removed; it's purpose is to get you started. If you have any questions about any part I'd be happy to explain.

Comment: Hi Sam, very grateful for your codes and your assumptions.
Because in my actual work excel files, there are 15 column header names, and each tab in the file has slightly different names, I tried this software: http://bulkfilemerger.com/index1, it worked quite ok for this case, anyway very thankful for your help :)

Comment: You're very welcome, glad to help and also glad you found something that works for you. You might want to answer your own question and mark it as answered so others that come across this question can see where the solution was. Best of luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this software and it worked: http://bulkfilemerger.com/index1